# Getting monitor size in python

Tags: python, monitor, fullscreen, pygame

I am using python and want to create a fullscreen window. I know about the pygame.FULLSCREEN flag but when I use that there's areas of black around the screen. Is there any way to get the monitor size using python so I can make the window the correct size?

Comment: You probably mean the screen resolution in pixels, which is different from the monitor's phyiscal size (which is extremely hard to detect, if at all). Maybe you want to edit that into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html), `pygame.display.Info` gives you a `VideoInfo` object that has, among other attributes:

> `current_w`, `current_h`:  Width and
>   height of the current video mode, or
>   of the
>       desktop mode if called before the display.set_mode is called.

`pygame.display.list_modes` gives you a list of the available fullscreen resolutions, e.g., per a comment in the docs:

```
>>> pygame.display.list_modes()
[(1920, 1080), (1768, 992), (1680, 1050), (1600, 1200), (1600, 1024), (1600, 900
), (1440, 900), (1400, 1050), (1360, 768), (1280, 1024), (1280, 960), (1280, 800
), (1280, 768), (1280, 720), (1152, 864), (1024, 768), (800, 600), (720, 576), (
720, 480), (640, 480)]
```

largest to smallest.  You should try some of these possibilities with `pygame.display.set_mode` to see which one looks good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
screensize = pygame.display.list_modes()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screensize[0][0], screensize[0][1]))
```