# How can I change screen resolution on windows 7 (using Java or Python code)?

Tags: java, python, screen-resolution

I have been searching all day and I couldn't find a solution to my problem. IMPORTANT: I don't want to change the resolution of a JFrame or a GUI application, I want to be able to alter the System resolution when I run the app.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838201/resize-display-resolution-using-python-with-cross-platform-support